# Indent output of an program waiting for required remote interaction in ksh

Tags: ksh

Using ksh93, i have a local binary program which prints a few lines of output containing a PIN code that should be entered on a remote system. When the correct PIN is entered on the remote system, this is automatically detected and the local program completes. I don't have to provide any local input to the program.

I'd just like to indent each of the program's initial output lines with a few spaces.
Since the following waits for command to complete, i can't see the output i require containing the pin :

command | nawk '{ printf "%2s%s\n", "", $0 }'

I've looked into ksh co-processes, but i can't seem find a solution. I have the feeling i'm making this more difficult than it probably is...

Comment: I don't know what to do with a command asking for input. For indenting I normally use `command | pr -tro 3`.

Comment: Well, not a solution in this case, but i didn't know yet about pr -o, so thanks.